# Encrypting a non-user-specific piece of data

Tags: encryption

There's a single, particular, global (i.e. not relative to any particular user) piece of data that I need to store (and potentially change) in the database used by my web application.

Its value should be encrypted at the database level, but users of my web application should be able to read its decrypted value, without typing themselves any passphrase.

Users of this web application are authenticated via a conventional username/password mechanism.

**Is it possible to implement an accessible, encrypted value as described?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes - that is possible, just encrypt and decrypt the data with the encryption key when you need it. The real question is how you get hold of the encryption key, when your program needs it. Your options depends on the level of security you want in your application.

Some options:

- Use a **tamper resistant cryptocard** and use keys that can't be exported from this card. All encryption and decryption takes place on this card. Prevents data from being decrypted without access to the card.
- **Enter the key manually at startup** (or use a smartcard/usb stick etc.), and only keep it in memory. Somebody running with at backup of the data won't be able to use it, unless they remembered to get the key from memory also.
- **Obtain the key from an other external system** each time it's needed. The data thief would need to steal the key another place as well.
- **Store the key another place than the database.** On another server, under another user etc. minimizing probability of access to both data and key.

Really secure solution to this kind of things are often quite cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. None of proposed solutions happen to be convenient for my application, but that doesn't prevent them from being good!

Answer (score 1):

If your database itself is considered secure you might provide stored procedures that make this data acessible. You can then put the encryption keys into a table that your users cannot read but allow them to execute the stored procedure that in turn is allowed to read the key.

Stored procedures vary for each database product but today most allow this in some way. You might even create a view that decrypts on access and uses a trigger to encrypt changes.

Comment: Great solution, provided, as you say, that the database is considered secure.